# forcing excel to display a negative number as ($0,000)

Tags: excel, vba

how do i do this in vba?

and how do i do this manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the number format of a cell to a custom format like:

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "0;(0)"
```

That will put parentheses around negative numbers.

If you want to display it exactly like ($0,000) you can do that with

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "0;(""$0,000"")"
```

You can set the custom format manually through the Format Cells dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with a cell formula.
=IF(A1<0, 0, A1)